# return row that share a value and which have at least one matching another condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, logic

I am looking for an elegant and efficient solution.
I found a quick and dirty solution. But I would like to know if there is a more "pandas way" to do.

I have a pd dataframe:

```
Id   Value
T4    0.4
T5    0.3
T5    0.9
T5    1
T6    0.8
T7    0.2
T7    0.8
```

I want to retrieve id that appears at least twice and have at least in one-row Value <= 0.4.

here the expected output is [T5, T7]

my solution, for now, consists to iterate through all unique value of Id make a sub df and check there are more than 2 rows and that at least once Value is inferior or equal to 0.4

any helps appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `groupby`:

```
g = df.groupby('Id')['Value']

df[g.transform('size').ge(2) & g.transform('min').le(0.4)]
```

Output:

```
   Id  Value
1  T5    0.3
2  T5    0.9
3  T5    1.0
5  T7    0.2
6  T7    0.8
```

If you only need the `Ids`, we can do:

```
g = df.groupby('Id')['Value'].agg(['size','min'])
g.index[g['size'].ge(2) & g['min'].le(0.4)]
```

which gives:

```
Index(['T5', 'T7'], dtype='object', name='Id')
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a built-in function that did it more efficiently, but here is what I came up with:

```
counts = df['Id'].value_counts()
filtered = df[(df['Value'] <= 0.4) & ([counts[i] > 2 for i in df['id']])]
```